# What does the inverse background efficiency represent?

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider, data-analysis, particle-detectors

I am reading a paper from the ATLAS experiment on the identification of tau jets from background jets and came across this figure:

[image]

I am struggling to find what the formula is for the inverse background efficiency. Can someone explain to me how this is calculated?

Here is the link to the whole paper: http://cdsweb.cern.ch/record/2064383/files/ATL-PHYS-PUB-2015-045.pdf

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inverse [background] efficiency" (also known as "[background] rejection") is calculated as the reciprocal of [background] efficiency.

In more detail (using $\tau$ identification as example), let's say you have a collection of objects, a portion of which are true taus and the remaining portion of which are not taus. Apply your $\tau$ identification procedure; then the "signal efficiency" would be calculated as

\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_\tau = \frac{\text{number of true $\tau$ identified as a $\tau$}}{\text{total number of true $\tau$}}
\end{equation}

However, there will also be some fraction of the not-taus in the collection of objects that could look like a tau, and thus be identified as a tau. So similarly there will be a "background efficiency"

\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_b = \frac{\text{number of not-$\tau$ identified as a $\tau$}}{\text{total number of not-$\tau$}}
\end{equation}

and from this, the rejection value is calculated as $1/\varepsilon_b$.

Answer (score 2):

A definition is given at the beginning of secion 5.3.

> The performance of the tau identification algorithm in terms of the
> inverse background efficiency, 1/εbkg versus the signal identification efficiency, εsig is shown in Fig. 9.
> The identification efficiency is defined as the fraction of 1-prong (3-prong) hadronic tau decays that are reconstructed as 1-track (3-track) τhad−vis candidates, which also pass the BDT selection criteria. The
> efficiency is the product of the reconstruction efficiency defined in section 4.3 and of the identification
> efficiency.

I'm not an expert in this field. But it reads to me like the background efficiency is akin to a false positive probability, and the signal efficiency is akin to a true positive probability. So Fig. 9 is a kind of [ROC curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic), but with the inverse false positive probability instead of the false positive probability.